# AAC ffmpeg encoding iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264, flv, aac

So I have spent most of the day writing an FFMPEG client for iOS, and I ran into a problem when trying to convert my hardware encoded h.264/aac mov file to h.264/aac flv. I borrowed the `muxing.c` example code and converted it to modern objective-c. I'm having problems with the aac encoder, which says...

[image: console logs]

I would like to know if it's possible to either add the `-strict -2` command at runtime, or compile the library with experimental encoders enabled?
Also, my library seems to be missing some encoders (i only tried speex and mp3). I compiled them with:

```
./configure \
--prefix=armv7 \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--enable-avresample \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk" \
--target-os=darwin \
--cc="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" \
--extra-cflags="-arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=6.1" \
--extra-ldflags="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=6.1" \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=cortex-a9 \
--enable-pic
```

and other variations, depending on the architecture. If someone can offer insight to either of my problems, it would be greatly appreciated!